# cannot access magento: report errors magento

Tags: magento

After install sample data, can't access magento. when enter 127.0.0.1/magento. It shows "The requested URL "127.0.0.1/magento/errors/report.php?hsimp=yhse-001" cannot be found or is not available. Please check the spelling or try again later.".

I m new to magento, please can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in magento/errors folder maku sure u gave a local.xml. If not dont worry just rename the local.xml.sample to local.xml
if it still shows error then go to phpmyadmin and select your magento database
then find core_config_data table, in there, check the web/unsecure/baseurl and we/secure/baseurl values in path and value fields.
make sure that those values are correct.
This actually causes because sample data overwrites the data.

Comment: check fields path and value fields there search for those values

Comment: that means sample data overwritten the database. that's why you are unable to access it insert these values(7,default,0,web/unsecure/base_url,http://[host/magento]) and (8,default,0,web/secure/base_url,http://[host/magento]) or u can even import this data from other magento installation database.

Comment: it happens because of the sample data.
install a fresh copy export the database, install sample data and import the Only table core_config_data it will work.
Or u can edit sample data.sql find this table in that sample data file and remove that block which deals with core_congif_data it may work but it may not achieve the purpose.

Comment: this table must exist with the data in it. so need to insert the above data into it. then only it will work

Comment: when you are just adding data to only this table manually from phpmyadmin no effect wil take place to the remaining data.

Comment: the problem is with core_congif_data table in the sampledata.
try removing this table in SAMPLE DATA(not in database) and re-install then reimport.
It wil work.

Comment: reimporting without reinstalling wont work. reinstall then reimport or manually insert the data selva.

Comment: yes but if it is difficult you have no choice than inserting the data manually

Comment: one defines the table structure and other one is to insert the data into the table remove those two.

Comment: when u have installed the sample data? does it worked after installing sample data?

Comment: however as u said there is no data in core_config_data, you might need data in this table

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29039/how-to-restore-core-confg-data-in-magento

check them

Comment: GO to Database, find admin_user table. There will be only one record. Click on edit change the password to your desired field DONT FORGET to change function field to MD5.

Comment: ya thats it in the password field remove enter your desired password and before to it there is a dropdown list is there right. select md5 from that and save it.

Comment: finally i can say that the problem is with the sample data

Answer (score 0):

To check the error you need to check the folder as magento store error reports in the folder:

`var/report`

check the report for more detailed error.

Possible steps that could help:

- remove cache and sessions
- check PHP error logs

Fix the errors and try to check the magento url.